# Register a Device in Cognito from Sign-in

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to register a device in Cognito from sign in in our iOS app with using the AWS Mobile SDK. I'm referencing the AWS blog post [Tracking and Remembering Devices Using Amazon Cognito Your User Pools](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tracking-and-remembering-devices-using-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/), but I am getting a null return and the device does not show up for the user in Cognito. The steps I followed are described in the AWS blog post and shown below. I also included the null return description. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing or suggest another way to try.

```
// User Sign In Functions
CognitoManager.shared.login(emailId, password: password, callback: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> (Void) in
      if(success)
      {
        let lc = LicenseCheck()
        lc.getLicenseUserInfoAgain(_email: emailId)
        let response = CognitoManager.shared.registerUser?.updateDeviceStatus(true)
        print("response \(response)")
      }
func updateDeviceStatus(_ email : String){
    let user = pool!.getUser(email)
    user.updateDeviceStatus(true)
    let deviceToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: LoggedInUser.shared.deviceToken) as! String
    let response = user.updateDeviceStatus(deviceToken, remembered: true)
    response.continueOnSuccessWith { (task :AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserUpdateDeviceStatusResponse>) -> Any? in
      guard task.error == nil else {
        print("Error")
        return nil
      }
      print("Success")
      return nil
    }
  } 

**// Return Value
response Optional(<AWSTask: 0x127644f50; completed = YES; cancelled = NO; faulted = YES; result = (null)>)**
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you print the error? `print(task.error)`

Comment: The response I get when I call the method updateDeviceStatus is
response <AWSTask: 0x12b31ddb0; completed = NO; cancelled = NO; faulted = NO;>. I guess the continueWithSuccess block is not getting called and not able to go into that code block and unable to print task.error

Comment: don't use continueWithSuccess, just use continue, in order to catch the error

Comment: task.error is Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorDomain Code=13 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=InvalidParameterException, message=1 validation error detected: Value 'ZbDQMwP8AlqNAqRpM228gtorrvHCcIRNR3mxmS9SBvs=' at 'deviceKey' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+_[0-9a-f-]+})

Comment: so your device key is not valid

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov Thanks a lot for your time. 
I tried decoding mu deviceKey but that didn't work.And tried using updateDeviceStatus(true) removing deviceKey and getting 
task.error is Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorDomain Code=-3000 "This device does not have an id, either it was never tracked or previously forgotten." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This device does not have an id, either it was never tracked or previously forgotten.}). Do you have any idea or can u plz assist if possible.